# Checkbox gets unchecked only after two clicks are made

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm working on an image selector of sorts. The idea is to have a list of images that can be selected via `checkbox`. If a user clicks on the image (which is inside a label element) the checkbox gets checked and that element (image) gets cloned to another called `#selected-items`.

The problem arises after trying to remove the selection by unchecking the element (clicking the image again). It takes two clicks to make the checkbox unchecked. The first click removes the cloned element from `#selected-items` but another click has to be made to uncheck the checkbox.

I'm trying to uncheck the selection and remove the cloned element with only one click. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/J4emr/

```
<div id="selected-items"><span></span></div>
<div class="field-widget-outfit-builder">
 <div class="form-type-checkbox">
   <input class="form-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>  
   <label>
     <img typeof="Image" src="" width="100" height="100"/>
     <div class="checkmark"></div>
   </label>
 </div>
</div>



$(".form-checkbox", context).live("click", function() {     
  var container = $(this).closest(".field-widget-outfit-builder");
  var checkbox = $(this).parent().find("input");
    if(checkbox.attr('checked')) {
       container.find(':checked').next().find('.checkmark').addClass('selected');
       container.find(':checked').next().find('img').addClass('opacity20');
       $(this).parents('.form-type-checkbox').clone()
              .appendTo("#selected-items").addClass("cloned")
              .append('<div class="remove"></div>');
       $("#selected-items").find("span").hide();
    } 
    else {
       $(this).attr('checked', false);
       $(this).closest(".cloned").remove();
       $(this).parents('.form-type-checkbox')
              .find('.checkmark').removeClass('selected');
       $(this).parents('.form-type-checkbox').find('img')
              .removeClass('opacity20');
    }
});
```

Comment: Looking at just JS code sometimes is not easy to solve the problem, so please also post the HTML code or even better some jsfiddle link.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I added the html code. Hopefully its easier to comprehend now!

Comment: If possible please provide code on JSfiddle. It would be a great help!!

Comment: JSfiddle added! As you can see it takes two clicks to get the checkbox unchecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is when unchecking the checkbox in the cloned element, you should have access to the original checkbox so that you can set its `checked` to false, with that logic you have to save the reference to the original checkbox as some property of the cloned checkbox. Then your problem will be solved. Also note that you must use `prop` to get and set the `checked` property instead of using `attr`.

**Updated code**:

```
$(".form-checkbox").live("click", function() {
  var container = $(this).closest(".field-widget-outfit-builder");
  var checkbox = $(this).parent().find("input");

  if(checkbox.prop('checked')) {
    container.find(':checked').next().find('.checkmark').addClass('selected');
    container.find(':checked').next().find('img');
    //save the checkbox into the property originCheck
    $(this).parents('.form-type-checkbox').clone()
                .appendTo("#selected-items").addClass("cloned")
                .append('<div class="remove"></div>')
                .find('input')[0].originCheck = checkbox;
    $("#selected-items").find("span").hide();
  }  else if($(this).parent().hasClass('cloned')) { 
     //set the checked on the clicked checkbox together with the original one 
     //to false
     $(this).add($(this.originCheck)).prop('checked', false);       
     $(this).closest(".cloned").remove();
     $(this).parents('.form-type-checkbox')
            .find('.checkmark').removeClass('selected');       
  }
});
```

### [Updated Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/cV8Xu/6/)

Comment: There are still some ***bad*** things in your original code, but I concentrated on solving your actual problem than fixing all the bad things. In fact I added CSS style to fix one of those problems.

Comment: Absolutely incredible, thank you! ...Oops yeah the html/css/js logic was all wrong in that example. Kudos to you for providing an answer even with all that mess.